# Help with finding the integrating factor of the differential equation $y'+y \cot (\cot x)=y^4\sin(\sin x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'+y \cot(\cot x)=y^4\sin(\sin x)$

I am aware that this is a Bernoulli DE.

$y^{-4}\frac{dy}{dx}+y^{-3}\cot (\cot x)=\sin({\sin x})$

Let $u=y^{-3}$ and $du=-3y^{-4}dy$

$\frac{du}{dx}-\frac{u \cot (\cot x)}{3}=-\frac{\sin (\sin x)}{3}$

The integrating factor is $\mu$

$\mu = e^ {-\int\frac{ \cot (\cot x)}{3}dx}$

Solving for the integral

$\int\frac{ \cot (\cot x)}{3}dx=$?

Now I am having a difficulty with this integral. Can someone assist me here? Thank you.

Comment: You do not need/have to evaluate the integral in order to solve for $y(x)$. You can leave the integral unevaluated.

Comment: @Nasser that would mean that I will have $ue^{-\frac{\cot ( \cot x)}{3}}=-\frac{1}{3} \int \sin (\sin x) e^{-\frac{\cot (\cot x)}{3}} $?

Comment: Basically yes. Just call the integrating factor $\mu$ like you did, and just use it as symbol from now on. At the very end, you say something like: Where $\mu$ is and now give the unevaluated integral. Nothing wrong with this if the integral can't be solved.